# SQL Server JOIN table as variable

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do the following where the `@POtable` variable and `@ProdID` will be passed to the stored procedure. The `@POtable` name shall be one of the `Order` table in the database, that I shall select randomly. I know that the following statement is incorrect, what would be the right syntax?

```
Select * 
From Products 
Join @POtable On Products.ProdID = @POtable.ProdID
Where ProdID = @ProdID
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need Products.ProdID in your where clause as the name is ambiguous. Also, I do not really understand what your question is actually about.

Comment: You cannot parametrize table and/or column names - if you want to do this, you **must use** dynamic SQL (e.g. building up the SQL query *as a string*, and then executing it). Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) first, to get an idea of what you're getting yourself into ....

Comment: Could you please post the complete procedure?

Comment: You may want to rethink your approach if you need dynamic table names. Perhaps there is a way you could have a static table name and use plain T-SQL which is easier to upkeep and has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments,you can't use variables in Tablenames,column names,Databasename,function names...

To use variables you have to use dynamic SQL..

```
Declare @potable Nvarchar(200);
Set @potable='sometablename';

Declare @SQL nVarchar(max)
Set @SQL='
Select * 
From Products p
Join '+QUOTENAME(@POtable)+' po On p.ProdID = po.ProdID
Where p.ProdID = '+@ProdID;

Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: There's a syntax error and it's also open to SQL injection. I suggest `Join "'+replace(@POtable,'"','""')+'" po` instead.